# Sql query to get one instance in text type

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in which there is a column of type text and i am putting data with comma separated values.

```
S.No   Text

1      A,A,A,B,B,C,A
2      A,B,B,C,A
3      A,B,B,C,A
4      B,B,C,A
5      B,B,C
```

So these are the two columns in which i need to update text so that it only contains A single time

Output

```
S.No   Text

1      B,B,C,A
2      B,B,C,A
3      B,B,C,A
4      B,B,C,A
5      B,B,C,A
```

Is there a way to do that in mysql
I tried to do with replace but unable to do.

Comment: See normalisation. And result 5 looks wrong

Comment: I guess a cell **must** contain an `A` by looking at the 5th row, right?

Comment: Yes every row must contain a single 'A'

Comment: So basically, you have to strip out all A's, then add one? I suggest you [edit] your question, the fact that we have to ask all these clarifications means that your question is not complete. You are also not saying anything about the order of the characters (which I guess is irrelevant), and your samples suggest a pattern of B,B,C always being present (which I guess is not the case either)

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you are looking for

```
SELECT
    No,
    REPLACE(Text, 'A,', '') AS Text
FROM
    your_table
```

**Edited:**

```
SELECT
    TT.No,
    CONCAT(REPLACE(REPLACE(TT.Text, 'A,', ''), ',A', ''),',A') AS Text
FROM
(
    SELECT 1  AS No,    'A,A,A,B,B,C,A' AS Text FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 2  AS No,    'A,B,B,C,A'     AS Text FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 3  AS No,    'A,B,B,C,A'     AS Text FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 4  AS No,    'B,B,C,A'       AS Text FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 5  AS No,    'B,B,C'         AS Text FROM DUAL
) TT
```

[Fiddle Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/38719/0)

Comment: 'A' should always be there wheter the text has or not. ALso what you are saying will not work if text is A,B,C ... it will be B,C .. which is wrong. It Should Be A,B,C

Comment: this is what you said is your desired output!, update your question and clarify what you want to get exactly

Comment: ah, sorry, just noticed that you want an A at the end, I'll update my answer

Comment: @SudhanshuGupta Simsim took the trouble to update his answer, now you take the trouble to update your question please.